# Clarification on the Application of Newton's Second Law

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, acceleration, friction, free-body-diagram

I'm having trouble understanding how to apply Newton's Second Law in certain scenarios. I understand the basic equation $F = ma$, but I'm confused about how to use it in situations where the forces involved are not straightforward.

For instance, I'm trying to analyze the motion of an object on an incline plane with friction. Can someone help me understand how to set up the equations and determine the acceleration of the object? I'm not looking for a complete solution, but rather some guidance on how to approach such problems conceptually.

Additionally, it would be great if someone could explain how to determine the direction of acceleration in different scenarios. I've encountered cases where it's not immediately clear whether the object will accelerate up or down the incline.

I believe that understanding these concepts will not only help me with my current coursework but also benefit others facing similar challenges.

Comment: Hello ! Welcome to Phys.SE. can you be a little more specific? as of now, it is difficult to understand what exactly you are looking

Comment: I want to calculate the acceleration of a 2-kilogram object placed on a 30-degree incline with a coefficient of friction of 0.2.

Here's what I've done so far: I've broken down the forces into components along the incline and perpendicular to it, but I'm having trouble determining the correct equations to use and how to account for the frictional force. 
I've already tried using F = ma, but I'm unsure about how to incorporate the frictional force. Any help with this specific problem would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Hint: calculate normal force and then friction. Then check if value of liming friction exceeds the $mg\sin\theta$. If yes, then balance it with the same force. If not (which is in this case), then friction is acting upwards. (All of this assumes the wedge is fixed

Comment: It all starts with a free body diagram.  let's see your free body diagram.

Comment: I appreciate your guidance, and I understand the importance of creating a free body diagram in solving this type of problem. However, I currently do not have a free body diagram prepared. Could you please provide some guidance on how to construct an appropriate free body diagram for the object on the inclined plane with friction?

I would greatly appreciate any assistance in creating a clear and accurate representation of the forces involved in this scenario.